# What is the state of Ruby on Rails with .NET integration?

Tags: .net, ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, authentication

I'm thinking about moving to Ruby on Rails but need extremely good integration with .NET components and most of all windows authentication pass through in and out of my application. Is this posible?

Thanks in advance/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use [IronRuby](http://ironruby.net/):

> IronRuby is an open-source implementation of the Ruby programming language which is tightly integrated with the .NET Framework. IronRuby can use the .NET Framework and Ruby libraries, and other .NET languages can use Ruby code just as easily.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that nowadays, a simple IronRuby on Rails can work like a charm. With [IronRuby](http://www.ironruby.net/), you have access to all .NET componets. After, it's a matter of you selecting what you need and how you want them to interact.

There's quite info and feedback about this subject on SO :

- [IronRuby On Rails VS. Ruby On Rails (Getting Started)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600257/ironruby-on-rails-vs-ruby-on-rails-getting-started)
- [Getting Started with IronRuby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386950/getting-started-with-ironruby-on-rails)

And outside. [This article](http://geekswithblogs.net/iupdateable/archive/2010/03/10/guest-post-using-ironruby-and-.net-to-produce-the-lsquohello.aspx) is quite interesting in order to understand how Ruby and .NET components can interact.

I couldn't find the real state of Rails 3.X on IronRuby.